Find lines in Vim that start one way and that don't end in another way
I'm trying to use Vim to find, via /, lines that start and end in specific ways. In particular, I'd be looking for lines that start with the character > and without the string RNA at the very end. For example, I would want to find this line
>NM_001010867.4 Homo sapiens iron-sulfur cluster assembly factor IBA57 (IBA57),transcript variant 1, mRNA; nuclear gene for mitochondrial product

in a search, but not find this line
>NR_107042.1 Homo sapiens microRNA 8075 (MIR8075), microRNA

I've looked hard for a solution but haven't been able to find one. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Are you sure you want to do this in vim? Assuming this is a multi sequence fasta file, I suspect there will be much better and more efficient ways of doing whatever the real end goal is. It might be worth asking on [bioinformatics.se].

Shouldn't this vim question be asked on the vim stackexchange? https://vi.stackexchange.com/

@Rob Vim questions can be asked here without issue.  If a user wants or requires a more specialised audience, then they may ask their Vim-related question on the vi-site, but since the various StackExcheange sites have such a large topical overlap in general, one sometimes cannot say that a question is better suited here or there.  See e.g. Ubuntu questions here, or questions on the Ubuntu site that don't actually relate to Ubuntu in particular. You could also argue that it would be appropriate to ask this question on the bioinformatics site...

/^>.*[^R][^N][^A]$
Also can use grep (without the leading /)

This would also weed out any line ending in e.g. DNA.

This works if your dataset is limited.  But as pointed out, it weeds out some variations.

Use:
^>\(.*RNA$\)\@!

Where \@! is the negative look-ahead operator, specific to vim, equivalent to perl's (?!...).
So it means: match on > at the start of the line (^), provided it's not followed (\@! applied to the \(...\) group) by any number (*) of characters (.) followed by RNA followed by the end of the line ($).
The same with \very-magic where most extended operators don't require the \ prefix:
^>\v(.*RNA$)@!

(here enabled after > as > itself with very-magic would be a word boundary operator).
^>.*[^R][^N][^A]$ from @user10489's answer is wrong because it fails to match on > RXX for instance or any line whose last character is A or whose second last is N or third last is R or has fewer than 4 characters.
>.*[^(RNA.)][\n] from @Romyo's answer doesn't make any sense whatsoever as [^(RNA.)] matches any single character other than R, N, A, ., ( or ).

Interesting.  Annoying that the extended stuff isn't standardized at all.

@user10489 it would be possible to do it with standard EREs, but the regexps in standard vi are BREs (with some extensions such as \<, but irrelevant for this purpose), which don't have support for alternation, so would not make it possible.

Many thanks. That said, it made sense to me to move .* out of the group, i.e., /^>.*(RNA$)@!. In other words, look for lines that start with ^, have any number of characters after that, but don't end with "RNA." Seemed to work, but am I misthinking anything?

@MarkPauley, that wouldn't work. ^>.*\(RNA$\)\@! matches on > RNA for instance, because that's for instance > RN (which matches >.*) followed by A (which is not RNA), though in effect as * is greedy that will match > RNA (which matches >.*) followed by the empty string (which is not RNA).

:/>.*[^(RNA.)][\n]

Out of these lines
helo
hello
>helloRNA.
>helloN00
>hell]RNA.
>twm0

only >helloN00 and >twm0 are selected
Here

/> means it shall begin with >
.* means match any number of characters
[^(RNA.)] don't end ^ with these string
[\n] end of the line


Thanks, but I don't understand the need for the period after the 'A.'

I think it's easier to use $ for the end of line?

This will not find any line that ends with R, with N, or with A (or with a dot or left or right parenthesis).
